# Matrix production in cpp

Tags: c++, gcc, matrix, product

I wanted to read and use(product) `'dat'` files in `cpp` 
There is matrix in each files. I already did reading files. 
but, I couldn't product them. what should I do?, profs

Comment: Production == multiplication?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommand to use a 3rd party library to calculate the linear algebra related topics, like http://arma.sourceforge.net/. You basically load your data to an armadillo matrix and you can do a lot with it ;)

Comment: I can't use Eng very well. so, I just read some words in your mention. Can I understand your Link(http://arma.sourceforge.net/)?? do i??